# Minikube failed to start: "node 'minikube' not found"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubelet

I have a virtual machine with Minikube inside it.
It works great when I run it using `minikube start --vm-driver=none` command.

My host crashed and therefore also the virtual machine. I rebooted the host and then the virtual machine and when I tried to run minikube  it failed with lots of information:

```
[root@ubuntu]$ minikube start --vm-driver=none
Starting local Kubernetes v1.13.2 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Stopping extra container runtimes...
Starting cluster components...
E0710 01:30:34.390608   42763 start.go:376] Error starting cluster: kubeadm init: 
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 


: running command: 
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 

 output: [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.13.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING FileExisting-ebtables]: ebtables not found in system path
    [WARNING FileExisting-socat]: socat not found in system path
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube" could not be reached
    [WARNING Hostname]: hostname "minikube": lookup minikube on 10.240.0.2:53: server misbehaving
    [WARNING Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Activating the kubelet service
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/var/lib/minikube/certs/"
[certs] Using existing ca certificate authority
[certs] Using existing apiserver certificate and key on disk
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [minikube localhost] and IPs [10.240.0.23 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [minikube localhost] and IPs [10.240.0.23 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Using existing up-to-date kubeconfig file: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
[kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.

Unfortunately, an error has occurred:
    timed out waiting for the condition

This error is likely caused by:
    - The kubelet is not running
    - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)

If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:
    - 'systemctl status kubelet'
    - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'

Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.
To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI, e.g. docker.
Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:
    - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'
    Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:
    - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
error execution phase wait-control-plane: couldn't initialize a Kubernetes cluster
: running command: 
sudo /usr/bin/kubeadm init --config /var/lib/kubeadm.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--data-minikube --ignore-preflight-errors=Port-10250 --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-scheduler.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-apiserver.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-kube-controller-manager.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests-etcd.yaml --ignore-preflight-errors=Swap --ignore-preflight-errors=CRI 

.: exit status 1
================================================================================
An error has occurred. Would you like to opt in to sending anonymized crash
information to minikube to help prevent future errors?

To disable this prompt, run: 'minikube config set WantReportErrorPrompt false'
================================================================================
Please enter your response [Y/n]: Prompt timed out.
Bummer, perhaps next time!


minikube failed :( exiting with error code 1
```

When I run `minikube status` I received:

```
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Stopped
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 10.240.0.23
```

It seems that there is problem with the API server.  The kubelet server is running but has errors like that:

```
kubelet.go:2266] node "minikube" not found
```

I run `minikube logs` and I see the same errors:

```
://localhost:8443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
Jul 10 01:35:52 ubuntu kubelet[43030]: E0710 01:35:52.587064   43030 reflector.go:134] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://localhost:8443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dminikube&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused
Jul 10 01:35:52 ubuntu kubelet[43030]: E0710 01:35:52.590979   43030 kubelet.go:2266] node "minikube" not found
```

It seems that it has some problem to connect to 127.0.0.1:8443 and therefore send error that the "minikube" not found.

I saw that this issue was already mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2967#issuecomment-423915639) but I tried the solution and it didn't work for me.
I stopped minikube and delete it and start it over again but the same problem appear.

Any idea what is the reason for this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [minikube dashboard returns 503 error on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916548/minikube-dashboard-returns-503-error-on-macos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like that:

```
minikube stop && minikube delete
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
reboot
```

After reboot it started correctly.
But I still didn't understand how it could be fixed without the restart.
The restart is was the missing piece. If you would do these command without restart and try to start it again, it won't start.

Comment: maybe you don't need reboot

Comment: minikube is local playground throw away environment and u can always fix it by starting over gain

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error comes when we run the docker in the swarm mode

A simple solution to this problem could be to run the following commands:

```
$ docker leave swarm
$ docker network prune
```

Comment: it's docker swarm leave

Answer (score 0):

These three simple steps should fix your problem

```
minikube stop
minikube delete
minikube start
```